# Is normal distribution the only class of distributions closed under addition?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

When I add two random variables that have a normal distribution, I get again a normal distribution. Is a normal distribution the only one with this property?

Comment: The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) has the property for sums of independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

If a collection of random variables is **jointly** normal then any linear combination of them is normal. There are many other classes of distributions with this property. For example the class of stable distributions with a particular index has this property.

Comment: For definition of stable distribution see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution